# I need live conversation

Tags: conversation, speech

Where (what Internet site) can I get a good, continuous conversation in real time from?

I need some sort of resource where I have the possibility of just sitting there listening to the conversations of others and optionally being able to answer, but that it isn't like a between just me and somebody else.

I feel that I learn too little with English videos and audio. Having Video-Audio subtitles for English-English or English-Native is the best option I have so far.

But I really need to get my ears fully used to natural conversation instead of things read from script. Spontaneous conversations are much more confusing to my ears than a very-well-pronounced script.

Comment: You won't be able to answer, but the easiest way to listen to natural conversations on the internet is to listen to a podcast. Try the Nerdist, Smodcast, Howard Stern Show (radio but can find on youtube), or one of the many BBC podcasts. You'll probably want to pick one with 2 hosts as that's the easiest to follow. Another choice would be to watch panel shows like 8 Out Of 10 Cats. However those tend to have a variety of accents and rhythms which can be difficult to understand. I would say chat shows but they don't tend to have natural conversation.

Comment: Given that this is about conversational use of English, should this question be migrated to ELL?

Comment: If you don't mind having no subtitles, YouTube can be your great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question about learn to speak fluent English? If so, podcasts would probably be a good choice. Some may follow scripts, but others can be very spontaneous and free-flow discussion. Radio broadcasts (talk shows) also follow such a format.

In this case you might not be able to answer audibly. If you podcast is steamed online, you have a possibility to text-chatting.

Suggestions: Video game podcasts tend to follow a general "topic list" but free-flow discussion. Your local radio stations might have talk shows, but nation-wide Howard Stern (might be inappropriate to you) and his cast are a good choice.